# Attaching lines or arrows to data labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I've been trying to visualize over 6k datapoints in a simple dotplot using ggplot. My threshold for y-value is set at 1, and is visualized using black and red for values >1 and <1 respectively. Because of the huge deviations in y-value I tried to implement breaks on the y-axis, which eventually resulted in a loss of certain datapoints present within the breaks. For that reason I've chosen for a zoom function instead to highlight the amount of datapoints around the threshold level.

There are certain datapoints that I would like to highlight in this graph. I've been using `geom_label` for this, but now I would like to also attach these labels to the actual datapoint. I've been searching for a way to do this, but the only function I've found that allows these is `geom_text_repel`.

The current code I have going is as follows

```
ggplot(Data1, aes(x= Number, y= Ratio)) +
  geom_point(col = ifelse(Data1$Ratio >1, 'black','red'), size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_label(data = Data1[Data1$Gene == "MB" ,], aes(Number,Ratio, label = Gene), hjust = 2) + 
  geom_label(data = Data1[Data1$Gene == "MYH7" ,], aes(Number,Ratio, label = Gene), hjust = 2)+
  geom_label(data = Data1[Data1$Gene == "CKM" ,], aes(Number,Ratio, label = Gene), hjust = 2)+
  geom_label(data = Data1[Data1$Gene == "VLDLR" ,], aes(Number,Ratio, label = Gene), hjust = 2)+
  geom_label(data = Data1[Data1$Gene == "LPAR3" ,], aes(Number,Ratio, label = Gene), hjust = 2)+
  facet_zoom(ylim = c(0, 50))
```

[image: Fig 1]

As you can see there are also some of the highlighted labels missing. My question is, is there a different way to label these points and get the label to be attached to the actual point?
(I am also open to other feedback regarding the plot itself)

Comment: You only need one call to geom_label, with something like `data = Data1[Data1$Gene %in% c("MB", "MYH7") ,]`. What went wrong with geom_label_repel?

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for the very late reply. I rewrote the code again including the simplified version of the labels and suddenly the `geom_label_repel` worked. In the end I decided to split the graph into two to make the data more clear to the reader into exactly how many points fell below the threshold (in red) by log transforming the y-axis in one of the graphs, including the labels. So thank you again for the help.